# Please convert my Gradient into multi browser work

Tags: css, gradient

I have the following Gradient:

background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top , #FFFFFF 0px, #DDDDDD 100%) repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;

but I have only this one line - could anyone please post for me a multi browser version of it?

Comment: I try already to import the Gradient in a Gradient Generator but don't work,... Its so beautiful I want to have this one. Please Help.

Comment: read the documentation of gradient, your gradient is very simple. a 5min reading and you can recreate it https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient

Comment: I don't search it for mozilla only - I search multi browser support !! Come one guys one must help me - if its so a small job for you just help me. Normally I use the CSS3 Generator but It don't work in this case.

Comment: do the effort to at least click the link and read. You read *mozilla* in the link and you assumed it's only for firefox. If you want us to help you should at least do some effort because I already helped you by giving you that link which contains everything you need.

Comment: Please can, a other person help me, please!!!

Answer (score 0):

http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

Try this website for generating a gradient color. And copy-paste the CSS, it should work in all browsers.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, I know this site and I am using it but it can't import my css right,.... "center top" is missing,...

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below css

```
  background: #ffffff;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top , #ffffff 0px, #dddddd 100%)  
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%, #dddddd 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to top, #ffffff 0%, #dddddd 100%); 
  /* 
     repeat, scroll,0 0  etc are background properties which can be broken 
     down as 
  */

  background-repeat: repeat;
  background-attachment: scroll;
  background-position:0 0;
  background-color: transparent;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. But what is with the "center", it don't look like my example: "center top , #FFFFFF 0px, #DDDDDD 100%", and the part:  "repeat scroll 0 0 transparent" is missing. Can you help me please a second time :)

Comment: @JamesWhite, Could you please share a screenshot of how it looks or a JSFiddle. As for the other parameters, I have updated my answer